# DataNucleus JDO model from database tables

Tags: java, orm, jdo, datanucleus

Is it possible to create a JDO model from an existing database using DataNucleus (or may be some other thirdparty tool)

There is a guide to generate the JPA model: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/guides/jpa/dali/eclipse_dali.html

Comment: AFAIK such a thing doesn't exist. Check this page for info: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/schematool.html#manual